# VS Code Go: Have an indicator next to a method that implements an interface

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, interface, indicator

I'm switching from GoLand to VS Code and there's one thing that I couldn't find an extension for so far and it's a way to have an indicator next to a method that implements an interface without actually right clicking it and go to implementations.

It makes it so easy to see right away that your method signature is right and jump to the implemented interface right away and from the interface to actual implementations of it as shown in the screenshots below.

[image: from interface implementation to interface]
[image: from interface to implementation]

Is there a way to do this in VS Code or would it be easy to make an extension to do so? If there's no way to do it yet and it'd be easy to make an extension for it, I would be down to do it 100%!

Thanks!

Comment: As an alternative, you can write something like `var _ Openable = (*WoodenDoor)(nil)` to make sure you get a compile-time check for interface compliance regardless of whether such an assertion exists elsewhere in the code.